# Read Values from a Speaker

Tags: arduino, led, pins

I am using Arduino UNO and did a project to sync LED to audio. I am not sure how to read a value from a speaker.

I connected a LED to Pin 9 (PWN) with 220ohms and ground. I connected A0 pin to a speaker pin and ground pin the other pin on speaker. I used the Smoothing example of arduino input and modified the code a bit to output to LED.  The speaker I used was with an old Phillips Music System and had only two pins. I played the music and led synced perfectly and everything worked fine. The project was a success.

Today I wanted to try to connect to a home theater (5.1 Sony HT-IV300 Model). This speakers also have same 2 pins. So I did everything same. A0 to Speaker pin 1 and Ground to Speaker pin 2. But suddenly the Music System went to power protect mode and A0 is stuck at ~1000 (975 - 977). I connected the arduino again with the Phillips Music System (Same setup) but A0 is always gives ~1000 value. Connecting to A1 and changing the code works perfectly fine!

Where did I go wrong? I cannot understand, what happened to A0 pin? What is the correct way to read the speaker values?

Thank You.
Abhi

Comment: You really shouldn't connect an ADC input to a speaker but rather to the line or head phone output.

Comment: You've probably destroyed the A0 pin by connecting it to the high powered speaker.

Comment: How could it be destroyed? Voltage is merely 0.15 volts (according to multimeter)

Comment: @DanD. Home Theater dose not have any direct audio out. Only speaker out and audio in (Some HDMIs)

Comment: Used the A0 as output and connected a LED (with 220ohms).DigitalWrite dose work but it only give half brightness when HIGH and dose not go to zero brightness at LOW. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could it be destroyed? Voltage is merely 0.15 volts (according to
>   multimeter)

If it were 0.15 volts and the speaker was an 8 ohm speaker, the power output to the speaker would be 0.15*0.15/8 = 0.028 watts. Does this seem likely or does it seem more likely that the multimeter isn't giving you the full picture?

If in fact you were driving 1 watt into the speaker, the RMS voltage would be 2.828 volts with a peak voltage of  that is significantly higher maybe 4 to 10 volts for music type signals.

This level of voltage and the level of current that the amplifier output is capable of providing will certainly damage an ADC input on a chip. Next time use a 10k resistor in series and maybe also a coupling capacitor.

Comment: Okay dont know so much about electrical terms.

Anyway I reread the Multimeter values
Speaker with wire
- 6.5 ohms
- 0.2 mv
Only Speaker (No wires Connected)
- 4.7 ohms
- No voltage (ofc :P)
Only wires
- 150 mv

Comment: Used the A0 as output and connected a LED (with 220ohms).DigitalWrite dose work but it only give half brightness when HIGH and dose not go to zero brightness at LOW. Hope this helps.

Comment: My answer still stands. That pin is broken.

Comment: I agree... it is broken no doubt (Can use for spare output though if needed). But still how can I connect another pin to the speakers to read the audio signal and sync a led, properly? A circuit would be nice :)

Comment: Last paragraph of my answer hints at a series resistor but without fully knowing what you want to do I can't really answer.

Comment: Ask whatever  you want to know... I will give the info. I need the Circuit so that I can do the project. I am out of ideas and afraid of frying the arduino in some way or another.

Comment: Look in the data sheet for the arduino - it will tell you to use diodes and resistors to protect inputs. You are also going to have a potential problem with earths on one piece of equipment clashing with earths on another so I'd recommend an audio coupling transformer with the output feeding the arduino at a biased up level so that the audio signal does not exceed the absolute maximum rails of the device. Nobody says interfacing is easy because you can get lucky or you can fry parts!